# Screen resolution is not displaying at the size it is set to

Tags: windows-7, display

My screen resolution setting is 1024x768 when I look it up by right clicking the desktop and choosing 'Screen Resolution'.  However, it is actually displaying at 800x600.

What is going on?

Specs:

- Windows 7 x86
- NVidia R210 latest driver installed
- Acer P166HQL Monitor

Comment: 800x600 is one of the resolutions handled by windows 7's generic driver. You will get that when the driver for your display card is not installed OR not working properly.  You already wrote that you had the latest driver installed.  Check if it is working properly (e.g. check event log, reboot, try again). Also, which resolution are try trying to set it to. If I googled the right monitor it should support 1366 x 768 and while 1024x768 should work native resolutions look a lot better.

Comment: You're right 1366x768 would be better.  Right now though, it doesn't matter what resolution I set it to.  The setting is being ignored.  Error log doesn't have anything that jumps out at me - what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this happens to anyone else in the future, check the following:

Right Click Desktop > Screen Resolution > "Make text and other items larger or smaller"

In my case, 'Larger - 150%' was selected for some reason.  So, the OS was correctly telling me the resolution, but some other process was shrinking it.  I was keyed in to the fact that something was off by the fact that the Windows Welcome/Login Screen was being displayed at the correct resolution.  It wasn't until I got to the actual desktop that the resolution was incorrect.